# Pandas groupby the same column multiple times based on other category column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `dataframe` that I am trying to use `pandas.groupby` on to get the sum. The values that I am grouping  are as follows:

```
    order_id    otype   score
0   id1 1   1.23
1   id1 2   1.56
2   id1 3   1.65
3   id1 4   1.73
4   id1 5   0.89
5   id2 1   1.07
6   id2 2   1.38
7   id2 3   0.94
8   id2 4   0.72
9   id2 5   1.37
10  id3 1   1.04
11  id3 2   0.56
12  id3 3   0.78
13  id3 4   1.12
14  id3 5   0.84
```

and I would like to perform a `.groupby` operation on `order_id` based on category values of `otype`, I want to create groupings based on otype as follows:

```
otype in [1,2,3] --> class1
otype in [4,5] --> class2
otype in [1,2,3,4,5] --> class3
otype in [2,3,5] --> class4
```

I would like the (very) end result to be a table looking like this:

```
   order_id    otype   score_sum
0   id1 class1   4.4
1   id1 class2   2.62
2   id1 class3   7.06
3   id1 class4   4.1
```

One way I can think of doing this is to calculate the result for each class separately and then use `pd.concat`.But I don't think this is a computationally efficient way, nor is it a code-simple way.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is the logic of `groupby`?

Comment: I don't understand the part class 3 overlaps on class 1 and class 2. Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Because large categories can be subdivided into small categories. The scenario I have come across is that 1,2,3 belong to revolving loan and 4,5 belong to credit card loan. These two types of business are liabilities. @PTQuoc

Comment: @Corralien I want to calculate the total score of different categories under each account(group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best is test both solutions in real data - but in my opinion `pd.concat` solution is simplier and if few keys in dictionary should be faster:

```
d= {'class1': [1,2,3], 
    'class2': [4,5],
    'class3': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'class4': [2,3,5]}

df1 = pd.concat({k: df.loc[df['otype'].isin(v)]
                      .groupby('order_id').score.sum() for k, v in d.items()})
print (df1)
        order_id
class1  id1         4.44
        id2         3.39
        id3         2.38
class2  id1         2.62
        id2         2.09
        id3         1.96
class3  id1         7.06
        id2         5.48
        id3         4.34
class4  id1         4.10
        id2         3.69
        id3         2.18
Name: score, dtype: float64
```

Alternative solution:

```
df1 = (pd.concat({k:df.loc[df['otype'].isin(v),['order_id','score']].assign(**{'class':k}) 
                     for k, v in d.items()})
         .groupby(['class', 'order_id'])
         .score.sum())
print (df1)
class   order_id
class1  id1         4.44
        id2         3.39
        id3         2.38
class2  id1         2.62
        id2         2.09
        id3         1.96
class3  id1         7.06
        id2         5.48
        id3         4.34
class4  id1         4.10
        id2         3.69
        id3         2.18
Name: score, dtype: float64
```

---

```
for k, v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['otype'].isin(v), k] = k
    
df = (df.drop('otype',1)
        .melt(['order_id','score'])
        .groupby(['value','order_id'])['score'].sum())
print (df)
value   order_id
class1  id1         4.44
        id2         3.39
        id3         2.38
class2  id1         2.62
        id2         2.09
        id3         1.96
class3  id1         7.06
        id2         5.48
        id3         4.34
class4  id1         4.10
        id2         3.69
        id3         2.18
Name: score, dtype: float64
```